# What library should be used for correct EXIF data parsing using PHP 7

Tags: php, exif

I keep getting error "IFD data bad offset ..." from PHP (now on version 7), when I try to read EXIF data from my JPG files. I tried general request for the data like this:

```
$exif = exif_read_data($filename);
```

So I tried to request just a section "FILE" - I got the same error.

```
$exif = exif_read_data($filename,"FILE");
```

Am I doing anything wrong? In case it is PHP issue, is there a library, which can read EXIF data without errors? I am interested especially in orientation and position.

I paced an example photo on http://foxtrot.cz/tmp/foto.jpg.

Comment: The error message sounds like a corrupted file. Are you sure the EXIF data can be read with other tools?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the way you're doing it, but this has had bugs in old versions in fact. Do you have a test case image? For me it just works with any image, apparently.

Comment: I have uploaded an example foto to http://foxtrot.cz/tmp/foto.jpg. I have been working on a photo library and I got the error for most of the photos (if not for all of them) ....